# Pass data from a form component to another component in react hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following form, and I need that when submitting the form, its information is displayed in a new component.

Perhaps the issue of redirecting to the other component could be done by creating a route. But I don't know how said component obtains the information of the form

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

import {useState, useRef} from 'React'

export default const FormX = () => {
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({
    name: "",
    priceUnitary: "",
    size: "",
    description: "",
  });

  const inputFileRef = useRef();

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    console.log(name, value);

    setFormValues({ ...formValues, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(formValues);
    console.log(inputFileRef.current.files);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form id="formu" onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="row">
        <h1>FORM SEND</h1>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input
            placeholder="Text input"
            name="name"
            value={formValues.name}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <label>Size</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            placeholder="Text input"
            name="size"
            value={formValues.size}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <label>Price Unitary</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            placeholder="Text input"
            name="priceUnitary"
            value={formValues.priceUnitary}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <label>Description</label>
          <input
            placeholder="Text input"
            name="description"
            value={formValues.description}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <label>File / Image</label>
          <input type="file" ref={inputFileRef} />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="color-primary">
          Save
        </button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
```

Link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/send-form-dcj5v?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Are you using `react-router` ? If yes, which version ?

Comment: @Shivam Jhan Yes, V6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can hide your form by change your state on form sumbit and display another component. You have to pass formValue as props in View component. Now think you have better idea what you have to do...

### Here i added new component, that display form value on submit

### App.js

```
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import View from "./View";

const FormX = () => {
    const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({
      name: "",
      priceUnitary: "",
      size: "",
      description: ""
    });
    const [isFormVisible, setIsFormVisible] = useState(true);

    const inputFileRef = useRef();

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        console.log(name, value);

        setFormValues({ ...formValues, [name]: value });
    };

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(formValues);
        console.log(inputFileRef?.current?.files);
        setIsFormVisible(false);
    };

    return (
    <>
      {isFormVisible ? (
        <form id="formu" onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="row">
          <h1>FORM SEND</h1>
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input
              placeholder="Text input"
              name="name"
              value={formValues?.name}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <label>Size</label>
            <input
              type="number"
              placeholder="Text input"
              name="size"
              value={formValues.size}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <label>Price Unitary</label>
            <input
              type="number"
              placeholder="Text input"
              name="priceUnitary"
              value={formValues.priceUnitary}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <label>Description</label>
            <input
              placeholder="Text input"
              name="description"
              value={formValues.description}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <label>File / Image</label>
            <input type="file" ref={inputFileRef} />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="color-primary">
            Save
          </button>
        </form>
      ) : (
        <View data={formValues} />
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default FormX;
```

### View.js

```
import React from "react";

const View = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Name: {data?.name}</p>
      <p>priceUnitary: {data?.priceUnitary}</p>
      <p>description: {data?.description}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default View;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's just what I needed. In addition, you provide me with great knowledge. Thanks a lot